# Como faço pra criar um espaçamento vertical entre divs no css?

Tags: html, css, angular

Estou com o seguinte problema, criei um componente de um botão e coloquei ele dentro de uma div, repliquei osso para 3 botões, queria saber se tem alguma propriedade no css para dar um espaçamento na vertical entre esses botões. Tentei com o line-height, mas n deu certo, pois acho q funciona só pra texto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a propriedade do css padding, se quiser espaçamento na vertical usa o padding-bottom ou padding-top, se quiser na horizontal é padding-left ou padding-right.
É possível combinar mais de um deles também.

Para usar seria assim:

No arquivo css:

```
.exemplo{
  padding-bottom: 10px; //Se quiser que seja relativo usa com % ao invés de px
}
```

No arquivo html:

```
<div class="exemplo">
....
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no css coloque assim:

```
div {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```